# faketime ignoring chronyc sources

Tags: terminal, command, time, chrony

I'm trying to do a "chronyc sources" call but with faketime. When in a terminal, "chronyc source|cat" works fine, but when I do `faketime 'last friday 5pm' chronyc sources|cat`, it outputs nothing.

whats even more odd is that I have an identical computer that works when I call chronyc with fake time.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it maybe some setup config I have messed up? I've tried reinstalling chrony as well as faketime.

Comment: I have not used faketime, but just read the man. I have a question: Why are you piping to cat? What happens if you just do faketime 'last friday 5pm' /bin/date ?? does that work??

Comment: @number9 theres something odd about this one machine for some reason that I have to pipe to cat otherwise itll output nothing (if you know how to fix that issue, maybe thatll help). When I do ```date``` it works, but not with my code or ```chronyc sources```

Comment: `faketime` works by monkey-patching time-related functions from the C library via a `LD_PRELOAD` hack. If that `chronyc` program is communicating with another server/daemon from where it gets its info, `faketime chronym` has a snowball's chance in hell of working correctly. At best, it will have no effect at all ;-)

Comment: In general, all `LD_PRELOAD` hacks will not work with a) static executables b) setuid/setcap executables c) other programs which override `LD_PRELOAD` with total disregard for its previous value d) program which use alternate calling paths -- overriding `open()` via `LD_PRELOAD` will not override the `open()` call from the libc's `fopen()`.

Comment: @user414777 this may be a rookie/silly question, but what are static executables? I dont think I'm doing any of those? 
Regarding the latter of the first post, doesnt the system time get its time from a different source and then faketime have to apply the offset? so if ntp says its yesterday and I say -1d, then itll be 2 days from actual right?

Comment: Static executables are a type of binaries which are self contained, and don't need an interpreter (aka dynamic loader) at runtime in order to run. `file /path` will tell you if it's a static or dynamic executable, and in the latter case, its interpreter. That `faketime` hack depends on the `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism, and  `LD_PRELOAD` **has no effect** on static exe's, and is also ignored for setuid, setgid or setcap exe's (`file` will also tell you if it's a setuid or setgid exe; `getcap` will tell you if it's a setcap one). Static executables are rare on desktop or server Linux systems.

Comment: `faketime` does not change the way your system is handling or reporting the time. It's only monkey-patching time-related library functions like `gettimeofday(2)`, `utimes(2)`, etc replacing them with wrappers which add or subtract an offset, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with SELinux. Apparently chrony doesn't interact well when SELinux is in enforced mode. I switched it to permissive and it behaves as expected now. I can call `faketime 'last friday 5pm' chronyc sources` as well as use it in my popen code